# Foreach results in numbered format

Tags: php, css, foreach, html-lists

I am using codeingiter and have soms results that i am showing from a database. The results are shown using PHP as follows:

```
 <?php
        if(isset($foo)){
            foreach($foo as $bar){ ?>
            <ol><li>
                <div class="results">  
                    <p class="name"><?php echo $bar['name']; ?></p>
                    <p class="address"><?php echo $bar['address']; ?></p>
                    <p class="address"><?php echo $bar['postcode']; ?></p> 
                    <span><?php number_format($bar['miles'],3) ?></span> miles               
                </div>
            </li></ol>  
            <?php
          }
        }
        ?>
```

I've also tried adding the class 'results' to the ol li.results and no luck. Have added a border and the border wraps around each result so i know my tags are in the right place.
CSS:

```
ol li {
    border:1px solid red;
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
```

In the reset.css i had this:

```
loads...of...elements including ul, ol and li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

I removed the ol, li from this and i got the numbers working but all have 1. for each result rather than 1, 2 3

These are shown as a list of addresses and i would like to have them numbered so the first one would have 1.RESULT 1, 2.RESULT 2 and so on... I've tried to use the ordered list tag and nothing seems to show up regarding numbers. i have checked in firebug and the tag is firing out for each one. Is this a css issue or the way PHP is showing the results?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You've got a `div` and `p` in your `ol` can you show your CSS?

Comment: what is in `class="results"` `class="name"` and `class="address"`

Comment: you need to put the <ol> tag outside the foreach loop otherwise you will get a lot of ordered lists containing one point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following

```
<?php if(isset($foo)): ?>
    <ol>
      <?php foreach($foo as $bar): ?>
      <li class='results'>
        <p class="name"><?php echo $bar['name']; ?></p>
        <p class="address"><?php echo $bar['address']; ?></p>
        <p class="address"><?php echo $bar['postcode']; ?></p> 
        <span><?php number_format($bar['miles'],3) ?></span> miles               
      <li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 6):

You forgot the `<li>` tags inside the `<ol>` tag

```
<?php
        if(isset($foo)){
            echo '<ol>';
            foreach($foo as $bar){ ?>
            <li>
                <div class="results">  
                    <p class="name"><?php echo $bar['name']; ?></p>
                    <p class="address"><?php echo $bar['address']; ?></p>
                    <p class="address"><?php echo $bar['postcode']; ?></p> 
                    <span><?php number_format($bar['miles'],3) ?></span> miles               
                </div>
            </li>  
            <?php
          }
          echo '</ol>';
        }
?>
```

Comment: apologies, these are now added in and still no luck. Checked my reset.css form and the following is in: ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}. when i changed this to say decimal the other elements on the page go numbered and even changed to ol li and ol, li and no luck.

Comment: just add it to the list you want. Change <ol> to '<ol class="myorderedlist">'; and set in css .myorderedlist{ list-style-type: decimal; }

Answer (score 1):

It's a CSS issue if the numbers are not showing. Common issue with reset stylesheets. Try adding:

```
list-style-type: decimal;
```

to your list style.

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, your `<OL>` and `</OL>` tags should stay outside the for cicle, while you should wrap your output between `<LI>` and `</LI>` inside the cicle.
Also, it's not a good practice to put DIVs inside LI elements, avoid it if you can by changing your styles.

Comment: All of the answers her seperate were not wokring but then adding the li, removing them from the reset and then adding the ol before the for each and the li after this worked - thanks everyone.

Comment: I hadn't seen your edits before answering, anyway I'm glad you solved your problem :)